# Change and update requirements for a composer vendor package

Tags: composer-php

I have a PHP project using composer. Among others there is this requirement:

/composer.json:

```
  "require": {
    .
    .
    "mypackage/backend": "^5.0",
    .
    .
   }
```

mypackage/backend requires a third package:

/vendor/mypackage/backend/composer.json:

```
  "require": {
    .
    .
    "mypackage/pdf": "branch/name",
    .
    .
   }
```

finaly mypackage/pdf requires a additional packages:

/vendor/mypackage/pdf/composer.json:

```
  "require": {
    "tecnickcom/tcpdf": "6.2.*",
    "setasign/fpdi": "1.5.*",
    "setasign/fpdi-tcpdf": "1.5.4"
  }
```

I want mypackage/pdf to require the latest versions respectively, like this:

```
  "require": {
    "tecnickcom/tcpdf": "6.4.*",
    "setasign/fpdi": "*",
    "setasign/fpdi-tcpdf": "2.*"
  }
```

So I want to do somethings like this:

```
composer require tecnickcom/tcpdf:6.4.4 setasign/fpdi-tcpdf:^2.3 setasign/fpdi:^2.3
```

but for the vendor package mypackage/pdf whithout to create another vendor folder in mypackage/pdf.

What is the composer way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composer won't/You can't. Composer is a dependency manager (not a package manager), that means, for your main (the root) project, it will resolve all dependencies for a matching version.

That means it either can or there are conflicts and it can't.

Composer however will never install dependencies deeper inside the vendor folder than the first `vendor/package-name` hierarchy.

You have such a conflict in your example: `"tecnickcom/tcpdf": "6.2.*"` prevents `"tecnickcom/tcpdf": "6.4.*"` and vice-versa.

When you try to "install" this, the dependency will result in version conflict errors as there is no version of that package that will full-fil all of the two constraints: `6.2.*`  and `6.4.*`.